# UITableView cell is visible through other cells during animation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I do have a “collapsible cells” in my UITableView. When user taps on a button within cell - it’s internal constraints are recalculated and cell changes it’s size - either to a smaller one or to a bigger one (collapse/expand). My problem is that when one of the last cells is expanded and then user collapsed it - this moving (and collapsing) cell is visible through other cells and between section’s headers - my reputation here is not high enough to show you a screenshot, unfortunately. Cell is built within .xib file, I tried to set “clip to bounds” parameter to TRUE to all views in the contentView of this cell - no effect. Does anybody have an idea - which direction should I look at?

Comment: Perhaps look at the opacity of cells?

Comment: Checked - problem is not woth that. Thinking about clipping and also possible problems with authomatic cell height calculation...